# how to read FormData object in php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Hello everyone I am posting a sample code in which I am uploading a file using Ajax JQuery. All thing works fine but I want to read the file content in my php code. So what is the syntax to read it?

```
    <?php

?>

<!--================================html==================================================-->

<html>
<head>
    <title>AJAX UPLOAD</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#Button_').click(function(){
                alert("hi");
                var name= document.getElementById('File_');
                 var alpha=name.files[0];
                console.log(alpha.name);
                 var data= new FormData();
                 data.append('file',alpha);
                 $.ajax({
                 url:'process.php',
                 data:data,
                 processData:false,
                 contentType:false,
                 type:'POST',
                 success:function(msg){
                 alert(msg);
                 }
                 });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" name="File" id="File_"/>
    <input type="button" name="Button" id="Button_" value="UPLOAD">
</body>
</html>
```

Now I do not know how to read the file data sent via Ajax. So please let me know the code

Comment: You read it just like you would if a form were being submitted. With `$_POST[]` and `$_FILES[]`.

Comment: i added $name=$_POST[]; now what parameter i have to pass in this bracket.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The first argument you pass to `FormData.append()` is the name of the form element that is passed to the server. So `data.append('file', alpha)` in your case is equivalent to `<input type="file" name="file">` - you passed 'file' to append() so 'file' is your input name.

You should find your stuff in `$_POST['file']` and `$_FILES['file']`. Next time try `var_dump($_POST);` after submit to see the array. :)

Learn about file uploads in php here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: var alpha=name.files[0]; can any one explain the meanning of this line in my code.

Comment: `<input type="file">` html elements have a property named `files`, which is an array of the JavaScript `File` object(s) selected by the user in that input field. It's an array because you can have multiple files selected if you use `<input type="file" multiple>`. Your example only allows one file, so selects `files[0]` to get the first (and only) file.

Comment: how to make changes to data.append('file',alpha); to append more tahn one file