# send (using Python) and receive (using PHP) files via API

Tags: php, jquery, python, api

how to send and receive files over an api. I want to send and receive pdf and image files over an APi. How can I do so? For example, the user sends the file using python (makes an API call using python) and I receive it at an endpoint (that uses PHP) and save it to file system. How can I send and receive files via API?

The API endpoint only accepts application/json

When someone sends me a file via API (written in python), how do I process the file using PHP??

Here's the solution I have so far:

base64encode the file on the python end
then base64decode the file on the PHP end.

The problem is I don't know how to retrieve the file by base64decoding it.

Does anyone know how to base64decode a file and save its contents to a database?

Comment: Did you try using "move_uploaded_file()" and get the file data using $_POST['file'] or $_FILES['file']? Did you get any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [FormData object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="fileinfo">
  <label>Your email address:</label>
  <input type="email" autocomplete="on" autofocus name="userid" placeholder="email" required size="32" maxlength="64" /><br />
  <label>Custom file label:</label>
  <input type="text" name="filelabel" size="12" maxlength="32" /><br />
  <label>File to stash:</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" required />
  <input type="submit" value="Stash the file!" />
</form>
<div></div>
```

and js

```
var fd = new FormData(document.querySelector("form"));
fd.append("CustomField", "This is some extra data");
$.ajax({
  url: "stash.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: fd,
  processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
  contentType: false   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
});
```

Comment: Probably this will help You
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834243/how-to-read-formdata-object-in-php

I'm not sure because i am not into PHP

Comment: I'm trying to do this in python not jquery