# Using FormData object with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, form-data

I am trying to send POST data using FormData object and XMLHttpRequest. As far as I understand this article - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects - I should receive the data in the same way as it's done when receiving from form submit action - so I expect $_POST array filled on my PHP side with all posted parameters. Unfortunately I receive the all data encoded in one string element:

```
"------WebKitFormBoundaryVOjgiuQUbsbzfzGz\r\nContent-Disposition:_form-data;_name" => "\"par1\"\r\n\r\ntest\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryVOjgiuQUbsbzfzGz\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"par2\"\r\n\r\ntest2\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryVOjgiuQUbsbzfzGz--\r\n"
```

My JS code is as far simple as this:

```
var fd = new FormData;
fd.append("par1", "test");
fd.append("par2", "test2");

req.open('POST', url);

req.send(fd);
```

What am I doing worng? Or is my understanding of the FormData object wrong?

Comment: Could you take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834243/how-to-read-formdata-object-in-php) and see if that helps

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly, what I would expect to happen - par1 and par2 from my example should be elements of $_POST array. Unfortunately, my $_POST has only one element - "------WebKitFormBoundaryVOjgiuQUbsbzfzGz\r\nContent-Disposition:_form-data;_name" - and I don't know what is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem--the API I was sending form data to did not recognize the data in the FormData object. I ended up using formData.entries() to populate my own request body.

```
async function submitContactForm(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let form = document.querySelector("form");
  let formData = new FormData(form);
  let reqBody = {};
  for (let pair of formData.entries()) {
    reqBody[pair[0]] = pair[1];
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(formData));
  let response = await fetch(
    "<myUrl>",
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(reqBody)
    }
  );
  let body = await response.json();
  console.log(body);
}
```

This seems pretty hacky, but I don't know why my API would not recognize the FormData instance I was sending.

Answer (score 0):

It's really easy to use `FormData` with `XMLHttpRequest`. See this example:

```
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // ...

    ajax.open("post", this.action, true);

    ajax.send(new FormData(this));

});
```

Full example in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/appelgran/asxu1dk8/).

Answer (score 0):

That happens because XMLHttpRequest's send function's default encoding when a parameter of type FormData is supplied is `multipart/form-data`.
See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData):

`It uses the same format a form would use if the encoding type were set to "multipart/form-data".`

Or [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) and [here](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#typedefdef-xmlhttprequestbodyinit) for more informations.

The encoding that you are trying to use is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which is the default encoding used by the HTML `<form>` tag when submitting.
If you want to send a FormData object using this encoding you can make use of the [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) interface:

```
// let's assume that the FormData object that you want to send is stored in
// a variable called fd
let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('POST', url);
req.send(new URLSearchParams(fd));
```

This works because, [as you can see](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#typedefdef-xmlhttprequestbodyinit), that's the default encoding used by XMLHttpRequest when provided with a parameter of class URLSearchParams.

All of this also applies to the newer `Fetch API`.