# ReactJS image uploading is not working

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to upload an image using the code sample given in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/hartzis/pen/VvNGZP)

I'm having the file contents in my state variable and getting it in the console from the below mentioned submit function

```
_handleSubmit(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log(this.state.file)
   payLoad = {
                image: this.state.file,
            }
   axios({
              method: 'post',
              url: this.state.url+'/task',
              data: payLoad,
              headers: {
                    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }
            })
 }
```

My console result of `this.state.file` is

```
File(128544)
lastModified:1508143324556
lastModifiedDate:Mon Oct 16 2017 14:12:04 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
name:"sample.png"
size:128544
type:"image/png"
webkitRelativePath:""
__proto__:File
```

But the Network shows image variable as `{}` in API request headers and image is not uploading. Can anyone help? As i'm new to ReactJS I'm really trouble in some features and forced to ask many questions here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [**FormData**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData), because you are sending a file with content_type as `content_type="multipart/form-data"`.

Try this:

```
_handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.file)

    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('image', this.state.file);

    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: this.state.url+'/task',
        data,
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    })
}
```

To check the FormData values you can use either [FormData.get(key)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get) or iterate over [FormData.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/values) method.

Check this snippet:

```js
let data = new FormData();
data.append('a', 1);
data.append('b', 2);
data.append('c', 3);
data.append('d', 4);

// using formdata.get(key) method
console.log('a = ', data.get('a'));

// iterating over values
for(let el of data.values()){
   console.log('el = ', el);
}
```

Comment: So if i need to add more variables, should i append all the values as `data.append('id', this.state.id);` like this?

Comment: yes you can append as many values you want, formdata is needed to send the file otherwise you can send the normal object :)

Comment: But in my backend PHP code $_FILES gives null array

Comment: not sure about php, check this answer may be solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834243/how-to-read-formdata-object-in-php

Comment: Yes, this is the method i'm following and i should get it.But unfortunately not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165816/discussion-between-mayank-shukla-and-hareesh-s-nair).